# indent options in shiny's selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to indent some of the options in a shiny `selectInput()` with extra spaces on the left of the names of the choices. However, all spaces in

```
selectInput("city_name",  "City", choices = "         Berlin")
```

are ignored and the `&nbsp;`s in

```
selectInput("city_name",  "City", choices = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Berlin")
```

get sanitized away.

Comment: You could try with preformatted text or spacers. Here are some options: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/indent.htm

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513153/shiny-extra-white-space-in-selectinput-choice-display-label/40540878#40540878) by @Alex Skorokhod might also be helpful. It basically uses `paste0(intToUtf8(160),"Berlin")` to add a space before the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't for the faint of heart but there are a bunch of unicode characters that are spaces of varying width (see [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)) that work just fine when used instead of regular spaces.

Comment: The dark side of the force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural.