# Shiny extra white space in selectInput choice display label

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am using selectInput in shiny and within the dropdown menu of my choices I want multiple white spaces between some words. However just including white spaces will not be displayed, in the app there will be at most one white space.

For instance in the code example below I have multiple spaces between "Cylinder" and "I", however if you run this only one will be displayed - how can I solve this?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
              c("Cylinder          I want multiple spaces here" = "cyl",
                "Transmission" = "am",
                "Gears" = "gear")),
  tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderTable({
    mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
  }, rownames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: I found some links with whitespace help using `pre()`, but because your extra whitespace is needed within the `selectInput` function call, it will be harder. The function takes in the values and creates html code on the inside. I don't see a way without digging into the source-code. Hopefully someone else can have more luck.

Comment: any way to overwrite the labels outside selectInput?

Comment: That would be a tough text parsing job. It's possible, but not practical.

Answer (score 5):

I usually replace space (ASCII 32) with "hard space" (ASCII 160).
In this case multiple spaces come undetected.

As RStudio does not accept ALT-160 as a " " one needs to use `intToUtf8(160)` to infuse symbol 160 dynamically.

Note: `base::strrep()` does not process symbol 160 properly so one has to use `stringi::stri_dup()` instead.

Thank you for comments suggesting to put generated name inside `selectInput()`. The resulting solution is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(stringi)


# Praparations (could be put into global.R) ------------
choices <- c(
  "TO BE OVERRIDEN" = "cyl",
  "Transmission" = "am",
  "Gears" = "gear")

# Replace name place holder with the actual one
names(choices)[1] <- paste0(
  "Cylinder",
  stri_dup(intToUtf8(160), 6), # Replace 6 with the desired number
  "I want multiple spaces here")

# Definition of UI -----------
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable:", choices),
  tableOutput("data")
)

# Definition of server -----------
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Main table
  output$data <- renderTable({
    mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
  }, rownames = TRUE)

}

# Run app -------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: any way to keep using selectInput? instead of adding renderUI?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no need to use `renderUI()`. Please see the updated code

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Personally I had to use `intToUtf8(8194)` (for "en space") to achieve something close to a 'monospace space'. See [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)